# How to replace all non numeric character from a string except any NewLine (\n) using regex?

Tags: regex, string, vb.net, replace

I have a **`TextBox`** with **`Multilined`** enabled. The **`TextBox`** contains a **`String`** that has numbers and other characters separated by a **`NewLine`** for example,

[image]

And I want to replace all the characters from the string except the numbers and the separator, **`NewLine`** or **`"/n"`**, as the **`String`** might sometime contains non alphabetic characters too like, **`'#', '%', '@', etc.`** but I am not able to construct a right expression to do this. I tried various expressions to match only number and **`NewLine`** for example,

> **`regex.replace(text,"[^0-9\n]","")`** - To match all numbers and **`NewLines`**, **`/n`**, and replace other characters with `Nothing` aka `""`.
>
> > But this only matches the numbers and does not recognize any **`NewLine`** as exception hence removes all characters along with **`NewLine`** resulting a single line String.
>
> **`regex.replace(text,"[^\n]","")`** - To remove all characters except **`NewLine`**.
>
> > But this does not replace any character from the **`String`**.
>
> **`regex.replace(text,"\n","")`** - To check if it recognizes any **`NewLine`** using **`\n`** or not.
>
> > In this expression it did recognize the **`NewLine`** and replaced all **`NewLine`**.

### My expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All characters except newline and digits is pretty straight-forward.

```
Regex.Replace(text, "[^\r\n0-9]", "")
```

Newline on Windows is CR (`\r`) and LF (`\n`). `0-9` can also be written as `\d`.

Comment: Didn't worked... It still giving as a single line string by removing all **`NewLine`** from the string. :(

Comment: Try also keeping `\r`.

Comment: Damnnnn That WORKED!!!!!! I was missing /r LOL I was bursting my head for this XDDD Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Non-numeric `[^\d]`
Non-newline `[^\n]`

---

Non-numeric, Non-newline `[^\d\n]`